# How can i get logs/debugging for an error 500?

Tags: asp.net, asp.net-mvc, iis, asp.net-core, .net-core

I'm working on a .NET Core 2.0 web application. I got a mocked database where application works good. Today i created a clean database and got this error 500 both on IIS Express and on regular IIS. 
The thing is: i couldn't debug why is throwing the error 500. The application just run.

I've currently tried:

- Check IIS logs by activating `stdoutLogEnabled="true"` and the only log created was:

> Hosting environment: Production Content root path:
>   C:\Users\pistolon\Downloads\peto Now listening on:
>   http://localhost:13361 Application started. Press Ctrl+C to shut down.

- Debugging from start the startup.cs file.

When I switch back to the mocked db it works without error.

Do you any of you could point me on where could i get an exception or log for this?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I don't believe this is enough information to go off of, however if you're seeing that 500 error when using the real database and the mock database is working appropriately, I would bet that your issue is with the connection string. You can also check to ensure that you're in the development environment as well.

Update: You can also try to use app.UseDeveloperExceptionPage();

Comment: app.UseDeveloperExceptionPage(); worked for me, thank you! i can see the error and debug it.

Comment: Just wanted to say that it tooks me 14 minutes to figure out how to fix the issue. Thanks! i spent all day on this!

Answer (score 3):

You can use [Event Viewer](https://www.howtogeek.com/123646/htg-explains-what-the-windows-event-viewer-is-and-how-you-can-use-it/) or [Visual Studio Remote Debugging](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/visualstudio/debugger/remote-debugging?view=vs-2017) to debug your deployed applications.

Also, you can use a logging framework like [Serilog](https://github.com/serilog/serilog) and use one of it sinks like [file sink](https://github.com/serilog/serilog-sinks-file) and create a middleware which catches and logs your exceptions and write their StackTrace, Message, Source to a log file that you can read them.

Here is ErrorHandlingMiddleware implementation :

```
public class ErrorHandlingMiddleware
{
    readonly RequestDelegate _next;
    static ILogger<ErrorHandlingMiddleware> _logger;

    public ErrorHandlingMiddleware(RequestDelegate next,
        ILogger<ErrorHandlingMiddleware> logger)
    {
        _next = next;
        _logger = logger;
    }

    public async Task Invoke(HttpContext context)
    {
        try
        {
            await _next(context);
        }
        catch (Exception ex)
        {
            await HandleExceptionAsync(context, ex);
        }
    }

    static async Task HandleExceptionAsync(
         HttpContext context,
         Exception exception)
    {
        string error = "An internal server error has occured.";

        _logger.LogError($"{exception.Source} - {exception.Message} - {exception.StackTrace} - {exception.TargetSite.Name}");

        context.Response.StatusCode = (int)HttpStatusCode.InternalServerError;
        context.Response.ContentType = "application/json";

        await context.Response.WriteAsync(JsonConvert.SerializeObject(new
        {
            error
        }));
    }
}
```

**Usage** :

```
app.UseMiddleware<ErrorHandlingMiddleware>();
```